# Magento Model Overriding error

Tags: magento-1.9

I am writing one extension in Magento that need to override Magento customer adapter class namely `Mage_Customer_Model_Convert_Adapter_Customer`.

But when I rewrite it and the profile it is showing me below error.

> Fatal error: Class ' Bs_Crm_Model_Customer ' not found in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\code\core\Mage\Dataflow\Model\Convert\Action\Abstract.php
>   on line 182

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bs_Crm>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Bs_Crm>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <crm>
                <class>Bs_Crm_Model</class>
            </crm>      
            <customer>                
                <rewrite>
                    <convert_adapter_customer>
                        Bs_Crm_Model_Customer
                    </convert_adapter_customer>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Model File.

```
class Bs_Crm_Model_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Convert_Adapter_Customer
{
    public function saveRow($importData){
        parent::saveRow($importData);
        $id = $this->getCustomerId();
         die($id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your config.xml and model file to review?

Comment: did you get your answer??

Comment: Please check i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.xml`, your model code should look like this.

```
<models>
    <crm>
        <class>Bs_Crm_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>crm_mysql4</resourceModel>
    </crm>
    <customer>
        <rewrite>
            <convert_adapter_customer>Bs_Crm_Model_Customer_Convert_Adapter_Customer</convert_adapter_customer>
        </rewrite>
    </customer>
</models>
```

and create a file named Customer.php on path `Bs/Crm/Model/Customer/Convert/Adapter/` and add following contents:

```
<?php 
class Bs_Crm_Model_Customer_Convert_Adapter_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Model_Convert_Adapter_Customer{
/* Your code here */
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have done the same thing in config file but still get error in admin site.

Comment: <global>
        <models>
            <crm>
                <class>Bs_Crm_Model</class>
            </crm>      
            <customer>                
                <rewrite>
                    <convert_adapter_customer>
                        Bs_Crm_Model_Customer
                    </convert_adapter_customer>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>
    </global>